# How can i stop elastic search to not tokenize words having hypen between them?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic search tokenizes the word if they have - between two or more words. For example, probably-not. It will tokenize it into two words. For more info [refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html)  But I don't want it. 
I know I can achieve the same thing using underscore instead of the hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a whitespace tokenizer. For example:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "text": "The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes jumped over the lazy dog's bone."
}
```

This will produce the following terms:

```
[ The, 2, QUICK, Brown-Foxes, jumped, over, the, lazy, dog's, bone. ]
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html